# Having trouble opening a virtual environment in python3.9

Tags: apt, python, environment

I have installed python3.9 through apt in my Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Then I was trying to create a new virtual environment that runs on 3.9. This is the process I did:

```
$ python3.9 -m venv /home/user1/py3.9
Error: Command '['/home/user1/py3.9/bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

To remedy this I tried upgrading pip, which raised an error regarding distutils. Here was the output of that:

```
$ python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils/__init__.py)
```

I then installed distutils using the command: `sudo apt install python3.9-distutils`, which was sucessful and after that I could upgrade pip.
But I'm still having the same problem of `returned non-zero exit status 1` if I try to create the virtual environment. I'm not sure what I did wrong. But I did install python3.11 in the past and could create virtual environment the same way IIRC. I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Warning: It's been a great five years with Ubuntu 18.04. But it's coming to an end: We will stop answering questions about Ubuntu 18.04 in nine days. Now might be a good time to migrate to a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Online tools like https://packages.ubuntu.com/ no longer provide details for anything older than 20.04 as the five years of support for *bionic* or 18.04 ended last month, so our ability to help is even more limited now. We'd need to have a *bionic* system around (to do enquiries at terminal) or have *devscripts* installed that allow searching of ESM releases such as 18.04 (*18.04 ESM official start date is 31-May-2023 so you're on-topic on this site until then*).  I'd suggest planning your *release-upgrade* asap too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did work out my own solution eventually. I guess from my part it was more of an inexperience. Also, I think it doesn't matter what ubuntu I'm using. The problem/solution should be same.

Answer (score 1):

Just installing python isn't enough. You have to to multiple steps:

```
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo apt install python3.9-distutils
sudo apt install python3.9-venv
```

Hopefully, after that everything will work as intended.

Comment: Hmmm. `-distutils` should have been included with a stock install. Most users should simply install Ubuntu, then install `python3.x-venv`. That's all they need.

Comment: Yeah. Dev is probably not needed. But I needed that for some other pip install stuff later. I edited and deleted that line.